# "STUFF" in sql server returning tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using the below mentioned code to concatenate distint nickname from `employee` table.

```
select @Approvers=stuff((select distinct ','+nickname as Approvers from employee 
    join daywisedetails on personid='XYZ' and 
    weekdate between '23-10-2013' and '30-11-2013' and 
    employeecode=approverid
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

with the above query, I get an answer as below

```
Approvers>,John H wiley</Approvers><Approvers>,Giridhar Murthy</Approvers>
```

But, I need something like below

```
John H wiley,Giridhar Murthy
```

I have done similar things earlier. I have not faced an issue like this. Can anyone suggest way to achieve this.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if you remove the column alias?, (in this case, remove `as Approvers`

Comment: In this recipe, `STUFF` just removes the first character(s) of the concatenated string that `FOR XML` has generated. I really don't understand why people focus on/describe this method of concatenation as being the `STUFF` method.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Is there any alternative which is effective, please do suggest me.

Comment: @PavanKumar Damien was just talking about why calling this method the `STUFF` method, since it's actually the `FOR XML PATH` command the one that makes the concatenation happen.

Comment: @Lamak : I can use `left` or `right` to achieve this. Right?

Comment: @PavanKumar The way you are using it is just fine.

Comment: @PavanKumar - Though those would require repeating the expression to get the length. `SUBSTRING` doesn't. `SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + name FROM sys.procedures FOR XML PATH('')),2,2147483647)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `as Approvers` alias